# PySpark create a json string by combining columns

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
input_schema = StructType(
            [
                StructField("ID", StringType(), True),
                StructField("Date", StringType(), True),
                StructField("code", StringType(), True),
            ])
input_data = [
            ("1", "2021-12-01", "a"),
            ("2", "2021-12-01", "b"),
        ]
input_df = spark.createDataFrame(data=input_data, schema=input_schema)
```

[image]

I would like to perform a transformation that combines a set of columns and stuff into a json string. The columns to be combined is known ahead of time. The output should look like something below.

[image]

Is there any sugggested method to achieve this?
Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a struct type and then convert to json:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
col_to_combine = ['Date','code']
output = input_df.withColumn('combined',F.to_json(F.struct(*col_to_combine)))\
                 .drop(*col_to_combine)
```

---

```
output.show(truncate=False)
+---+--------------------------------+
|ID |combined                        |
+---+--------------------------------+
|1  |{"Date":"2021-12-01","code":"a"}|
|2  |{"Date":"2021-12-01","code":"b"}|
+---+--------------------------------+
```